# Show nested list on click in Joomla (1.7.0)

Tags: javascript, html, css, joomla

I have an issue with Joomla displaying a navigation menu located on the left-hand side of the website. I want some submenus to open when I click their parent. The effect I want, is shown in the provided Codepen. But I want to click instead of hover over the item.

The thing with Joomla is that I have to link the "parent li-item" to an article. Even if I remove the href with javascript, joomla will reload the page if I click the "li"-item. This will undo the desired effect (I tried applying a specific class with javascript to set "display:none" to "display:block" on the nested list after clicking).

A solution with css, html, javascript or a joomla override would have my preference.

PS: I am aware I am using an old version of Joomla. I might be able to upgrade it in the near future (when I am granted access to the control-panel of the website).

PS2: I know there is a paid plugin that does this, but I'm working on a charity site and I'd like to keep plugins to a minimum. I'd also love to know how to do this in code!

```
HTML

<ul>
<li>
<a href="something">Click me and don t load this link with Joomla</a>
<ul>
<li>Show me on click (not hover)</li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

.

```
CSS

ul>li>ul{
  display: none;
}
ul>li:hover>ul{
  display: block;
}
```

[Codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/LNJzbE)

Comment: Can you provide a link to the actual website?

Comment: You can place url menu for Basis Eerste Hulp and set it to #. When you click it will just open submenu.

Comment: @mokiSRB No, unfortunately that won't open the submenu. It will simply refresh the page and add # to the current url. It is this refresh that causes the issue, because it wil "undo" my applied code to show the submenu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do it with this code:

The function hasClass checks if an element has a specific class.

The function menuMechanics disables the links. And adds or removes the class to show or hide the nested ul.

The final rules of code add the menuMechanics Function to all "has-nested-children"-class items after clicking it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function hasClass(element, cls) {
    return (' ' + element.className + ' ').indexOf(' ' + cls + ' ') > -1;
    }

function menuMechanics(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    if(hasClass(this.parentElement, "active") === true){
        this.parentElement.className = this.parentElement.className.replace("active", "");
    }
    else{
        this.parentElement.className += " active";
    }
}

hasNestedChildren = document.getElementsByClassName('has-nested-children');
    for(i=0; i<hasNestedChildren.length; i++){
        hasNestedChildren[i].addEventListener("click", menuMechanics);
    }
</script>
```